# How to apply setText() to onclicked item in Recyclerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I wanna upadate recyclerview child item when itself clicked.It takes the data from server and updates it self. kindly provide any solution for this scenario.Here i have tried as i know but it is not updating.

```
     myHolder.upvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(final View v) {
         SQLiteHandler db = new SQLiteHandler(context);
         HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();
         String tag_string_req = "req_login";
         final String uid = user.get("uid");
         Log.d("hello", uid);
         StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                 AppConfig.Upvote, new Response.Listener<String>() {

             @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
             @Override
             public void onResponse(String response) {

                 try {

                     JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                     boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                     if (!error) {
                         String upvote_no = jObj.getString("upcount");
                         String text = "Upvoted " + upvote_no;
                         ((TextView) v).setText(text);
                         //Log.d("resp", upvote);
                     } else {
                         // Error in login. Get the error message
                         String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                         Toast.makeText(context,
                                 errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     // JSON error
                     e.printStackTrace();
                     Toast.makeText(context, "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }

             }
         }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

             @Override
             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                 Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                 Toast.makeText(context,
                         error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         }) {

             @Override
             protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                 // Posting parameters to login url
                 Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                 params.put("qries_user_id", uid);
                 params.put("qries_answer_id", answered_id);

                 return params;
             }

         };

         // Adding request to request queue

         AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
     }
 });
```

In the above code i am trying to taking response from Json and updating to self child item as **((TextView) v).setText(text);** but it is not updating.Thanks in Advance!

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: The Above code is not working :-( ..It is not updating textview(upvote)

Comment: You have an issue in your code as `holder` and `myHolder` are 2 differents object when you should use `holder` in this method.

Comment: Try changing myHolder to holder

Comment: i have updated the question.Kindly check it

Comment: Using a recycler view you'd better to update your adapter data set to achieve this kind of feature. This the way I'll do it because here your TextView can be recycled and be associate to another item in your list.

Comment: i am not taking data from adapter.when it takes the data from server, it updates the child item.

Comment: In RecyclerView/Adapter conception, viewHolders are not consistent childs of your list but just temporary and recyclable holder of your item view. It's why I think you're not on the good way to achieve what you're trying to do, but maybe I miss something of your functional need.

Answer (score 2):

Try to cast your clicked view in TextView

```
     myHolder.upvote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            ((TextView) v).setText("something");
         }
     });
```